# Determine if Tomcat is Running with Ruby

Tags: ruby, tomcat, ps

I want to determine if Tomcat is running from a ruby script.  My idea is to run the following bash command to find if there is an associated PID for Tomcat

```
ps -axe | grep tomcat | grep java | awk '{print $1}'
```

When I run the command by itself in bash, it will return the PID if Tomcat is running, otherwise it will return nothing.

When I run the command from ruby

```
puts `ps -axe | grep tomcat | grep java | awk '{print $1}'`
```

A PID will always be printed, even if Tomcat is not actually running.  Why is a PID always returned in Ruby?  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return always a PID because `tomcat` and `java` are also part of the command you are using to check if `tomcat` is running. One way to check if `tomcat` is alive is to try to check if you can download a url from the tomcat server.

Comment: Did you try running the command in your system ? It does return junk value every time. But from the command line, it does not return anything.

Comment: Imagine you run `grep java`. Every time you run it and it gets a new process id and when it starts it's part of process list. Then it tries to find `java` in the process list and it finds itself!

Comment: Why does the same command return a junk number in ruby and not return a value when executed in the bash shell is the question i am asking. I understood the tomcat is a java argument, but the command line should also return a junk value right ?

Comment: Try bash -c 'ps -axe | grep tomcat | grep java'. So ruby runs it through the shell